# Unpack a PostGIS/PostgreSQL record with SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis

How would I write the following query using SQLAlchemy's ORM?

```
SELECT filename, (stats).*
FROM (
    SELECT filename, ST_SummaryStats(rast, 1, TRUE) AS stats FROM tiles
) AS stats_table;
```

Here, [`ST_SummaryStats`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SummaryStats.html) is a PostGIS function that returns the record that I wish to unpack. `tiles` is a PostGIS table with `filename` and `rast` (raster) columns. My attempt is as follows:

```
sub_q = db_session.query(
    Tiles.filename,
    func.ST_SummaryStats(Tiles.rast, 1, True).label('stats'),
).subquery()

q = db_session.query(
    sub_q.columns.filename,
    sub_q.columns.stats,
)
```

However, I don't know how to write the `(stats).*` expression -- and hence unpack the record -- with SQLAlchemy's ORM. Consequently, `stats` appears to be a tuple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ST_SummaryStats()` returns a `record`, so rather than use it as a `SELECT` expression (which would return the `record`), use it as a `FROM` clause and pick the desired statistics at the `SELECT` level, so it becomes very simply:

```
SELECT filename, count, sum, mean, stddev, min, max
FROM tiles, ST_SummaryStats(tiles.rast, 1, true);
```

This results in a so-called `LATERAL JOIN` and since `ST_SummaryStats()` returns only a single row for the indicated `raster` in `tiles` you do not need a join condition, filter or anything else.

I am not sure about SQLAlchemy's ability to use the result of a function as a class, but a sure-fire way of making this work is to wrap the above `SELECT` into a `VIEW` and then access the view from SQLAlchemy:

```
CREATE VIEW raster_stats AS
  SELECT filename, count, sum, mean, stddev, min, max
  FROM tiles, ST_SummaryStats(tiles.rast, 1, true);
```